# How to obtain last insert id?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert into two tables while taking the last inserted id and then adding it to the second table. I have already tried to use ExecuteNonScalar but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
string iquery = "insert into [User] (username, password, role) values (@username,@password,@role)";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(iquery, conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", "Customer");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //get last insert User ID, insert into borrower 
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        string iquery2 = "insert into [borrower] (userid, name, phone, email, type) values (@id, @name, @phone, @email, @type)";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(iquery2, conn);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I compile and run the code the id inserted is 0. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should alter a bit your sql statement:

```
string iquery = "INSERT INTO [User] 
                 (username, password, role) 
                 VALUES (@username,@password,@role)
                 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Basically, `SCOPE_INDETITY`

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
> the same scope.

For further info, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Furthermore, you don't need `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` before

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: so executenonquery and executescalar do the same thing ok thank you

Comment: @eBourgess No they don't do the same thing. You can call one or the other and they server different purposes. `ExecuteNonQuery` *Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected*. While `ExecuteScalar` *Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored*. In your case the latter is ok. However you can solve the problem (provided that you will change a bit your sql statement) by using the `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: alright, now it works for me and you solved another problem that was double inserting into table. thank you for your time and your explanation

Comment: You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)